# Spring Annotations when java file is compiled

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

I started learning spring today and i have a question regarding what happens to the annotations when java files with annotations is compiled ?. 
The reason i am asking this is because of the fundamental difference i see when we choose to use  the xml approach vs the annotations approach , and what i think is the philosophy of spring. The way i understand is spring says that all your java classes can be simple pojo's and all the spring related config should be kept independent (Like xml file.)

In case of developing spring application using xml *.java files have no idea about spring container and are compiled in to .class without any spring related dependencies.

But now when we annotate the .java file and the file is compiled the compiled file now has all spring related dependencies hard baked in to it and no longer are your classes simple pojo's.

Is this correct ? I am not sure if i am missing some thing here.

Comment: Java vs XML configuration is a matter of preference, in most cases they are interchangeable. Separation of concern is another matter, you should expose your classes through library-agnostic interface so they're not baked into a particular library (whenever appropriate).

Answer (score 1):

Annotations can be considered as metadata of a class or its element (method, field, local variable...). When you put annotation, you don't implement any behaviour. You just give additional info on an element.

That way, Spring, which is in charge of instanciating its bean can collect the info with [reflection](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaAnnotations/article.html) (see also [this site](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/annotations.html)) and process it.

To conclude, your Spring beans still remain POJO and there is no difference with the XML way (...from that point of view) since Spring gets from annotations the information it would have got from XML .

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right and your question is justifiable, that's the way how I think about it too.

Not only compiled code but also dependency on spring jars bother me. Once you use this annotations your resulting jar depends on spring library.

It's reasonable to store beans in model according to DDD but spring is some kind of infrastructure layer so I didn't like the dependency.

Even if you would use XML, it's useful for few placed to use attributes. E.g. `@Required` attribute which is useful to verify that linked bean was injected. So, I've decide to use constructor dependency injection to omit this attribute, see [my article](http://martin.podval.eu/2013/07/constructor-dependency-injection-over.html). I completely leave out the dependency on spring in the code.

You can probably find such *mind* hook for many annotation you want/force to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use annotations only for your configuration classes, without marking them actual bean classes. In such scenario if you not use spring you just not load configuration classes.